# Mysql select the data BETWEEN two STRING not integer

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im trying to do this in laravel using query builder. What i want is to output all the data between the 2 given string as my start and end.

Datas in my database:

### Columntitle

DataC_1
DataC_2
DataB_1
DataC_3
DataC_4
DataC_5

What i tried is:
Query builder in laravel:

```
DB::table('tablename')->whereBetween('columnname', array(DataC_1, DataC3))->get();
```

I also tried it in raw sql heres my code:

```
SELECT * From tablename WHERE columnname BETWEEN DataC_1 AND DataC3
```

What i expected output is DataC2

but the output is:

DataC_1
DataC_2
DataC_3
DataC_4
DataC_5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have identical strings you can compare them by just stripping the characters from them and then compare only the numbers. The following code will work:

```
DB::table('tablename')->whereRaw("REPLACE(columnname, 'DataC_', '') > 1
AND REPLACE(columnname, 'DataC_', '') < 3")->get();
```

This will give you the output `DataC_2`

[Manual for the REPLACE function in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: Hi @shaddy i have another question why is it that if i tried to change the ">"  operator to >=  it output error?

Comment: This condition should work just fine `REPLACE(columnname, 'DataC_', '') >= 1 AND REPLACE(columnname, 'DataC_', '') < 3` . Can you copy paste it and try? If it fails please post the error that you are gitting.

Comment: here is the generated error by laravel
--------
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=< 7' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `mmtable` where REPLACE(tableName, 'Tangkas10C_', '') >= 1 AND REPLACE(tableName, 'Tangkas10C_', '') =< 7)","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tangkas_admin_\\tangkas_admin_\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php","line":625

Comment: do you want me to edit my question and add my codes?

Comment: This `=<` is not valid operator. Valid operators are `>=` and `<=` . Change the second one and it will work :) Example `REPLACE(columnname, 'DataC_', '') >= 1 AND REPLACE(columnname, 'DataC_', '') <= 3`

Comment: oh yeah i thought i tried that, hahaha, thankx again